# How to add characters to filename using glob in Python?

Tags: python, character, glob, qgis

The following is a snippet of code. The script takes the input files from a "Test" folder, runs a function and then outputs the files with the same name in the "Results" folder (i.e. `"Example_Layer.shp")`. How could I set it so that the output file would instead read `"Example_Layer(A).shp"`?

```
#Set paths
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

def run():

    #Set definitions
    input = path_res + "/" + "input.shp"
    output = path_res  + "/" + fname

    #Set current path to path_dir and search for only .shp files then run function
    os.chdir(path_dir)
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):

        run_function, input, output
run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your  question:

*How could I set it so that the output file would instead read "Example_Layer(A).shp"*

You can use [shutil.copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to  copy the file to the new directory, adding a `"(A)"` to each file name using `os.path.join` to join the path and new filename:

```
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"
import os
import shutil
def run():
    os.chdir(path_dir)
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
        name,ex = fname.rsplit(".",1) # split on "." to rejoin later adding a ("A")
        # use shutil.copy to copy the file after adding ("A") 
        shutil.copy(fname,os.path.join(path_res,"{}{}{}".format(name,"(A)",ex)))
        # to move and rename in one step 
        #shutil.move(fname,os.path.join(path_res,"{}{}{}".format(name,"(A)",ex)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you did indeed answer my question :)

Comment: @Joseph, good, glad it helped :) If you did not want to keep the original you could use shutil.move.

Comment: Thanks again, I have used `shutil.move` and `shutil.remove` before but I think renaming the files would be safer for me =)

Comment: @Joseph, no worries, just thought I would mention it.

Comment: On second thoughts...I may need to delete the original files afterall! Is there a one liner you can provide please or shall I simply ask a new question regarding this issue?

Comment: `shutil.move` will do it in one step.  Just replace copy with move

Comment: @Joseph, I added the code, only change needed is .move

Comment: Many thanks Padraic! I was testing it and it works for most of the files as some were still in use but this is likely due to another part of the script. Thanks again buddy!

Answer (score 2):

You currently calculate the `output` variable once (which IMO wouldn't work since you don't have any `fname` defined yet).

Move the statement where you compute the output variable within the for loop, like below:

```
#Set paths
path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"

def run():

    #Set definitions
    input = path_res + "/" + "input.shp"

    #Set current path to path_dir and search for only .shp files then run function
    os.chdir(path_dir)
    for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
        output = path_res  + "/" + fname
        run_function, input, output

run()
```

Comment: This is correct. Stylistically, I'd also suggest using string substitution as opposed to string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I have re-structured my script. However, I accepted the other answer as it focused on how to rename the file (I perhaps should have re-worded the question better so apologies for that).